# I am trying to delete Vector2 item in List of Vector2 vectors comparing it with other Vector2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am taking Vector2 as touch postion,and i want to search for same Vector2 in list where i already added all positions rounded by 1 decimal f.e 0.5.But now they never seems to be same,I guess the vector taken from transform position has more decimals than 1.So how can i fix it.
Using debug i see that both list contains same values,but comparing them and trying deleting duplicates,doesnt work.

```
public class skriptaPozicija : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<Vector2> listaV1;
       List<Sprite> slike1t;
  public  List<Vector2> daseNeponovi;
    int randomBroj;

    public GameObject instantacija;
    GameObject oznacenaSl;
    Vector3 skala;
    public GameObject povecalo;

    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
       StartCoroutine(postavkeSLova());
        List<Vector2> daseNeponovi=new List<Vector2>();
       
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       // RemoveDuplicates();
    }

    public void klikNaPoziciju()
    {
        randomBroj = Random.Range(0,slike1t.Count);
        // Debug.Log("broj itema u slici"+HintoviMale.slikeT.Count);
        oznacenaSl = Instantiate(instantacija,listaV1[randomBroj] , Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        oznacenaSl.transform.localScale = new Vector3(WordsGrid.skalaPrefaba.x,
                        WordsGrid.skalaPrefaba.y, 0);
        oznacenaSl.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = slike1t[randomBroj];
       Destroy(oznacenaSl, 3f);

        slike1t.RemoveAt(randomBroj);
        listaV1.RemoveAt(randomBroj);
      
        if (slike1t.Count <= 0)
        {
            povecalo.SetActive(false);
        }

for(int i = 0; i < daseNeponovi.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(daseNeponovi[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listaV1.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(listaV1[i]);
        }

        listaV1.Add(new Vector2(2, 2));
        daseNeponovi.Add(new Vector2(2, 2));


    }

    IEnumerator postavkeSLova()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        slike1t = new List<Sprite>();
        for (int i = 0; i < HintoviMale.slike.Count; i++)
        {
            slike1t.Add(HintoviMale.slike[i]);
        }

        listaV1 = new List<Vector2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < HintoviMale.pozicijaV.Count; i++)
        {
            listaV1.Add(HintoviMale.pozicijaV[i]);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveDuplicates()
    {
        foreach (Vector2 item in daseNeponovi)
        {
            if (listaV1.Contains(item))
            {
                listaV1.Remove(item);
            }

        }
    }


    public void refreshList()
    {
        slike1t = new List<Sprite>();
        listaV1 = new List<Vector2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < HintoviMale.slike.Count; i++)
        {
            slike1t.Add(HintoviMale.slike[i]);
        }

        listaV1 = new List<Vector2>();
        for (int i = 0; i < HintoviMale.pozicijaV.Count; i++)
        {
            listaV1.Add(HintoviMale.pozicijaV[i]);
        }
    }


}
```

I am taking Vector2 as touch postion,and i want to search for same Vector2 in list where i already added all positions rounded by 1 decimal f.e 0.5.But now they never seems to be same,I guess the vector taken from transform position has more decimals than 1.So how can i fix it.

Comment: One solution would be to round the touch positions to integers (_Mathf.RoundToInt_) and store them in **Vector2Int**s. This way, you wouldn't encounter floating point precision issues.

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: i added code,thanks